# Vectorization of a gradient descent code

Tags: matlab, gradient-descent

I am implementing a batch gradient descent on Matlab. I have a problem with the update step of `theta`.
`theta` is a vector of two components (two rows).
`X` is a matrix containing `m` rows (number of training samples) and `n=2` columns (number of features).
Y is an `m` rows vector.

During the update step, I need to set each `theta(i)` to

```
theta(i) = theta(i) - (alpha/m)*sum((X*theta-y).*X(:,i))
```

This can be done with a `for` loop, but I can't figure out how to vectorize it (because of the `X(:,i)` term).

Any suggestion?

Comment: If `X` has size m x 2, `theta` is 2 x 1 and `y` is m x 1, how is `X*theta` defined? How do you subtract `y` from that? And how do you multiply the result times the column vector `X(:,i)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo. By using the rules of matrix multiplication

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh, I see. Sorry

Comment: @LuisMendo if `X` has size mx2 `theta` is 2x1 then `X*theta` is mx1 and we can substract `y` (mx1). The multiplication by `X(:,i)` is a term by term multiplication (`.*`)

Comment: @bigTree Sorry, my bad. I see it now

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do a simple matrix multiplication, the thing MATLAB is supposedly best at.

```
theta = theta - (alpha/m) * (X' * (X*theta-y));
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist works great thanks. By the way, I figured out this is not the good way of performing gradient descent for it doesn't update all the features simultaneously

Comment: Isn't this only correct where `X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1)]`? Because unlike `theta_1`, `theta_0` shouldn't be multiplied by `x^i` so `X` must contain a column of `1s`?

Comment: Can this be further simplified as theta - (alpha/m)*(theta - A' * y) ?

Comment: @XPD only if `X'*X == I`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer given by Mad Physicist, the following can also be applied.

`theta = theta - (alpha/m) * sum( (X * theta - y).* X )';`